# redirect didn't work in yii2 db transaction

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i use a Db transaction in my controller, when i run my project on localhost it work correctly, but when i run it on server it save data on db but it doesn't redirect to view and it just show blank page

```
if ($flag) {
    $transaction->commit();
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success',
    Yii::t('app', 'The Product number {id} has been saved.', ['id' => $model->id]));
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Comment: Did you check your error log ?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was because of one of my widget, now it work